# Auto-select/auto-checkbox row in Angular Material Table if List has only 1 value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-table

**Problem**: I'm trying to have my material table auto-select/auto-checkbox the 1st row in the table if the datasource[] has only 1 item in the list.

So if my datasource has 4 items, don't pre-select any of the rows, but if it has only 1 item returned, automatically select that row.

When I say select, I mean auto-checkbox that row **WITHOUT** having to click.

I haven't been able to find anything that fits what I'm trying to do.

`table.component.html` file

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="(dataSource$ | async) || []">
    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select" *ngIf="checkboxRequired">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-mdc-header-row checkbox table-header">
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="mat-mdc-row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                      class="checkbox">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-mdc-header-row table-header">
        {{column.header}}
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="mat-mdc-row">
        {{column.cell(row)}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="mat-mdc-row"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="mat-mdc-row" (click)="selection.toggle(row)"></tr>
</table>
```

`table.component.ts`

```
  @Input()
  dataSource$: Observable<FakeObject[]>;

  selectedRowIndex: number;
  selection = new SelectionModel<Columns>(false, []);
```

I'm not sure how to set the initial selected/checkbox array with an observable there, but I was hoping it could be done in the HTML somehow.

There's a long `columns` field that contains the column names, etc that I didn't add to the `.ts` code cause its unnecessary, but you can see it called in the *ngFor.

Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check your datasource by adding a pipe/tap and then conditionally adding the selection.

Somewhere else in your component when your input is set: (set method, onInit, etc...)

```
  this.dataSource$.pipe(
    tap((values) => {
      if (values?.data?.length === 1) {
        this.selection.select(values.data[0]);
      }
    })
  );
```

StackBlitz working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mqdnkz?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-selection-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-selection-example.html,src%2Ftest.ts

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am going to try this!!

Comment: While this appears to work for you, my dataSource is an @input of Observable<any>. ```@input dataSource$: Observable<any>``` because we have to re-use this table multiple times. And because it's already an observable I am not entirely sure how to get it to work like how you have it.

Comment: Have you tried creating a set method on your input? You could use it to define the observable with the pipe added

Comment: I have not, don't think I've ever seen that tbh.

Comment: I'd recommend giving it a try. Another option, and maybe the best thing you could do, is change your structure a bit so that the input is just your dataSource (not an Observable). Your parent component can manage the observable and pass the value to the input